# Simple Form Custom Wrapper, class on input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using the simple_form gem.

I have a custom wrapper, here is the code:

```
  config.wrappers :inlineBootstrap, :tag => 'div', :class => 'control-group', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label, :class => "col-lg-2"
    b.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls col-lg-10' do |ba|
      ba.use :input, :class => "form-control"
      ba.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-inline' }
      ba.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'p', :class => 'help-block' }
    end
  end
```

I want this line of code:

```
ba.use :input, :class => "form-control"
```

to generate the class on the actual input, what it does right now is generating a wrapper over the input and adding the class to the wrapper, not the input.

any sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on pull request [#622](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/pull/622), you specify the class within an array:

```
ba.use :input, :class => [ "form-control" ]
```

this fix only works on simpleform 3.0+

Comment: I am on version 2.1.1 for simple form, i think that merge is for 3.0+

Comment: im stuck on 2.1.1 couse im on a rails 3 project

Comment: In that case, I believe you are stuck with passing the class from the input itself as: `f.input :foo, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }` in your template.  I do not think what you are asking is possible in older version of SimpleForm.